# Algorithm for grouping to resolve collisions

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph

Algorithm question from Google:

A teacher wants to separate his problem students into two groups. He has a list of names(in pairs) which represents the students that can not be put into the same group. Our task is to check whether it is possible to separate all students without collision.

For example, if the list is:

```
Jack Jim (cannot be in the same group)
Jim Rose (...)
Rose Jack (...)
```

Then it is not possible to separate them all without collision.

My idea is to use the idea of graph, and use associate array or map to implement it. However, I think if there are many unconnected branches of the graph, it will be very complicated. Any one can help?

Comment: To deal with the issue of connectedness, consider dividing your set of names into equivalence classes. If two names are in a pair together in your list, they are in the same equivalence class.

Comment: This is where I have the question: When we traverse the list, it is possible that two pairs of names are unconnected at the beginning and I put them into different groups, but in the end they are connected by another components. If so, we need to  traverse the list many times. For example, the list is Jack_Jim, Ted_Peter, Peter_Jane, Jane_Julia, Julia_Jack.

Answer (score 4):

You want to check whether the graph is **bipartite**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Testing_bipartiteness) has details on how to do it.

Here is a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889036/writing-a-program-to-check-if-a-graph-is-bipartite) and a [Java implementation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/Bipartite.java.html) from Princeton.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a graph coloring problem.  Start by declaring that Jack is in the 'black' group.  This means Jim has to be in the 'red' group.  This means 'Rose' must be in the 'black group.'  Now we get teh collision: Because rose is 'black,' Jack must be 'Red,' but we already assigned him a black color.

---

Edit: Pseudocode for implementation (I haven't compiled it, and I know it leaks memory)

```
enum Group {
    UNKNOWN,
    RED,
    BLACK
};

struct Person
{
    string          name;
    Group           group;
    set<Person*>    exclusionList;
}

class Class
{
    public:
        void addExclusion(const string& inPersonA, const string& inPersonB)
        {
            bool first = (mMembers.empty());
            Person* personA = findPerson(inPersonA);
            Person* personB = findPerson(inPersonB);

            personA->exclusinList.insert(personB);
            personB->exclusionList.insert(personA);

            if (first) {
                // special case, assign initial colors
                personA->color = BLACK;
                personB->color = RED;
            } else {
                switch (personA->color) {
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        switch(personB->color) {
                            case UNKNOWN:
                                break; // we can't do anything, nothing is known
                            case BLACK:
                                setColor(personA, RED);
                                break;
                            case RED:
                                setColor(personA, BLACK);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case RED:
                        switch (personB->color) {
                            case UNKNOWN:
                                setColor(personB, BLACK);
                                break;
                            case RED:
                                throw "EXCLUSION FAILURE";
                            case BLACK:
                                break;
                       }
                    case BLACK:
                        switch (personB->color) {
                            case UNKNOWN:
                                setColor(personB, BLACK);
                                break;
                            case RED:
                                break;
                            case BLACK:
                                throw "EXCLUSION FAILURE";
                       }
                }
            }
        }

    private:
        Person* findPerson(const string& inString)
        {
            Person* rval = mMembers[inString];
            if (rval == null) {
                rval = new Person(inString, UNKNOWN);
                mMembers[inString] = rval;
            }
            return rval;
        }

        void setColor(Person* inPerson, Group inColor)
        {
            if (inPerson->color == inColor)
               return; // no op
            if (inPerson->color != UNKNOWN && inPerson->color != inColor)
               throw "EXCLUSION FAILURE";
            // now we know inPerson was UNKNOWN
            inPerson->color = inColor;
            for (auto iter = inPerson->exclusionList.begin(); iter != inPerson->exclusionList.end(); ++iter) {
                setColor(*iter, (inColor == RED) ? BLACK : RED);
        }

        unordered_map<string, Person*> mMembers;
};
```

Comment: The algorithm is incorrect, in the case both endpoints are uncolored, the exclution won't be checked. See @Clément's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#algorithm.coffee

#teacher wants to separate his/her problem prisoners into two groups by keeping 
#separated certain individuals. we have a list of kids and need to decide how to 
#separate them according to rules provided.  only two groups allowed apparently. if 
#more are required we are in collision situation.

reset = '\x1B[0m'
red   = '\x1B[0;31m'
green = '\x1B[0;32m'

#we list all the kids, and such that the values are arrays holding all problems associated with that
# key=kid

contras = 
  "abe": []
  "billy": []
  "bella": []
  "charles": []
  "dafner": []
  "echo": []
  "ferris": []
  "gomer": []
  "gina": []
  "heloise": []

#we have empty groups
group1 = []
group2 = []

# defining problem relationships
problems = [
  ["abe", "heloise"]
  ["bella", "dafner"]
  ["gomer", "echo"]
  #["abe", "bella"]
  ["heloise", "dafner"]
  ["echo", "ferris"]
  ["abe", "dafner"]
]
# with the problems array we can populate the contras object
for item in problems
  contras[item[0]].push item[1]
  contras[item[1]].push item[0]

# with the populated contras object we can determine conflicts

for key, value of contras
  for item in value
    for item2 in value
      for item3 in contras[item]
        if item2 == item3 and item3 != item
          console.log red + "There is a collision implicit in problem pair " + reset + key + red + " and " + reset + item + red + " because both " + reset + key + red + " and " + reset + item + red + " are problematic with " + reset + item3 + red + " who is also known as " + reset + item2 + red + ".\n"


# if there are no unresolvable conflicts then this routine below
# will work, otherwise you'll see a bunch of
# red flags thrown by the routine above.

for item in problems
  if group1.length == 0
    group1.push item[0]
    group2.push item[1]
  else
    duplicate = false
    for item2 in group1
      if item2 in contras[item[0]] then duplicate = true
    if duplicate == true 
      group1.push item[1] unless item[1] in group1
      group2.push item[0] unless item[0] in group2
    else
      group1.push item[0] unless item[0] in group1
      group2.push item[1] unless item[1] in group2




###  some tests
# checking if group1 contains problems
for item in group1
  for item2 in problems
    for item3 in item2
      if item == item3
        for item4 in item2
          if item4 != item
            for item5 in group1
              if item4 == item5
                duplicate = false
                for item6 in collisions
                  if item2 == item6 then duplicate = true
                if duplicate == false
                  collisions.push item2

# checking if group2 contains problems
for item in group2
  for item2 in problems
    for item3 in item2
      if item == item3
        for item4 in item2
          if item4 != item
            for item5 in group2
              if item4 == item5
                duplicate = false
                for item6 in collisions
                  if item2 == item6 then duplicate = true
                if duplicate == false
                  collisions.push item2

###

console.log green + "whole kids group is " + reset + kids

console.log green + "group1 is " +reset + group1

console.log green + "group2 is " + reset + group2

# console.log red + "collisions are " + reset + collisions
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to check whether your graph is bipartite (i.e whether the vertices of your graph are able to be assigned one of two colors in such a way that no edge connects vertices of the same color). If you number students in the class with integers:

```
1. Jack
2. Jim
3. Rose
```

you can solve this problem easily using Boost Graph Library in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/bipartite.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    typedef adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, undirectedS> vector_graph_t;
    typedef std::pair <int, int> E;

    E edges[] = { E (1, 2), E (2, 3), E (3, 1)};
    vector_graph_t students (&edges[0],&edges[0] + sizeof(edges) / sizeof(E), 3);

    if ( is_bipartite(students) )
        std::cout << "Bipartite graph" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Non bipartite graph" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```